# Checking for Null text from a bundle resulting in NullPointer

Tags: android, string, nullpointerexception, bundle

I've tried many different things, but I cant seem to get rid of this nullpointer. I have an app, in which the user has to input text into three EditTexts then press a submit button. I want to deal with the fact that if the user inputs no data and just presses submit, when the class is called where all the calculations are done, I can show a toast, and then use an intent to go back to the main.
However, it wont work, the if never gets looked at...

Here's the code

```
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();//the bundle is retrieved from the intent
    int id = b.getInt("ID");//retreive the ID to know which function to call
    int nullCounter=0;
    if (b.getString("vf").trim().equals(""))
        nullCounter++;
    else if (!b.getString("vf").trim().equals(""))//checks each possibility that could have been included in the bundle
    vf = Double.parseDouble(b.getString("vf"));//if the value exists, extract it and convert it to an integer

    if (b.getString("t").trim().equals(""))
        nullCounter++;
    else if (!b.getString("t").trim().equals(""))
    t = Double.parseDouble(b.getString("t"));

    if (b.getString("d").trim().equals(""))
        nullCounter++;
    else if (!b.getString("d").trim().equals(""))
    d = Double.parseDouble(b.getString("d"));

    if (b.getString("a").trim().equals(""))
        nullCounter++;
    else if (!b.getString("a").trim().equals(""))
    a = Double.parseDouble(b.getString("a"));

    if (b.getString("v1").trim().equals(""))
        nullCounter++;
    else if (!b.getString("v1").trim().equals(""))
    v1 = Double.parseDouble(b.getString("v1"));

    if(nullCounter >2)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Results.this,PhysicsCalculatorActivity.class);
        Results.this.startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: Hah I just added a try catch and it works, thanks for the suggestion, helped me realise I forgot to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your b.getString(...) returns null, not a "".

Check if b.getString(...) is not null, before call trim().